# Graduated symbols drawing order not displayed correctly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, symbology

When I use graduated symbols for a polygon layer to display population density, the layer is always displayed on top of all the other layers even if I dragged it to the bottom of the Table of Contents.

Any idea how to solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is you can't. The graduated symbols are treated more like labels (which essentially they are - special labels at the centroid of the polygon), which draw on top of all actual features. Layer order *will* control the draw order of various graduated symbol layers. It also controls the draw order of the *background* of a graduated symbol layer; just not the symbols themselves.

There is an Esri discussion thread on this at https://geonet.esri.com/thread/52106

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there a work-around for this?

Comment: Well that depends on what you're trying to do. If you're wanting to put a transparent layer on top of all your points, no. If you're trying to mask some points so they don't show at all while others do, you could edit your original data to remove the polygons you don't want displayed as dots (make a copy first of course). Alternatively, if it's the white dots you're trying to hide, remember that 'white' and 'no color' are two different things. If it's something else you'd need to edit your question to provide more detail on your end goal.

Comment: Thank you Chris. I am hoping to display the interstate highway line features on top of the dots. I'm not looking to remove any dots.

Comment: @Veronica The only way I can think to do that is to increase the weight ranking of that layer with respect to labels. Depends on which label engine you're using as to where to do that, and I'm not sure it would work. There is something odd going on in your screenshot though with highways being on top in the ToC but even the boundary lines are over them. Almost makes me think some kind of symbol level drawing is going on.